# How to Screenshare of my iPad on Mac

Tags: iphone, ipad, airplay, screensharing

I have a big demo of my iPad application to my client,i tried AirServer, Bomgar but those are not working to share my iPad Screen on the Mac. Can any one help me which tool i should use for screenshare of my iPad to Mac. If i can share my iPad screen on Mac, then i can share my Mac to the clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For screen sharing Reflector is the best solution. It's wireless mirroring means you can share your iPad screen on mac and then you can share mac to client.